# printf unexpected behaviour when printing after System() call

Tags: c, windows, printf

I have the following "main" function with the related console output.

```
argv[1] = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\InstallShield Installation Information\\0x041f.txt"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Please provide a file name with extension\r\n");
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned char buf[LEN_NORM];
    char filename[230];
    char ali_dirname[200];
    char bli_dirname[200];

    FILE *fp_obj, *fp_det, *fp_txt = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    //dirty?
    *(argv[1] + strlen(argv[1]) + 1 - 5) = '\0';
    snprintf(ali_dirname, strlen(argv[1]) + 4, "%s/ali", argv[1]);
    snprintf(bli_dirname, strlen(argv[1]) + 4, "%s/bli", argv[1]);

    char cmd[200];
    snprintf(cmd, strlen(argv[1]) + 12, "@RD /S /Q \"%s\"", argv[1]);
    printf("cmd: %s\r\n", cmd);
    system(cmd);
    printf("cmd: %s\r\n", cmd);
}
```

> cmd: @RD /S /Q "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\0x041f"
>
> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>
> tion Information\0x041f"
>   iles (x86)\InstallShield Installa

[image: Console output]

As you can see after the system call the console is completely broken.
I really cannot understand why this is happening. Any idea?

EDIT:
Thank you for the feedback, i thought that snprintf length was about the length of data one wants to write. "cmd" has a fixed length which is the maximum allowed size. According to the info i found online "size" is the maximum number of bytes(characters) that will be written to the buffer so in my case 12 should be the correct number (i checked with the debugger and the \" is correctly written) and not sizeof(cmd), am i wrong? I've tried with "12 + 1" (4 + 1) and with "sizeof" in all the "snprintf" cases but nothing changes

The code runs in the "main" (i've updated it)

If i remove the "System(cmd)" call the console output is fine!

Comment: Although this is not the issue here, the second argument to `snprintf()` should be `sizeof(cmd)`.

Comment: The size (second) argument to [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is the size of the *destination buffer*, typically something like `sizeof cmd` (in your case).

Comment: @ctx `sizeof(cmd)/sizeof(cmd[0])` always better. It doesn't matter in this case but... ;)

Comment: @LPs Hm, for array sizes in terms of number of elements in general, you are right, but I cannot imagine a situation where this might do anything good with `snprintf()` or string functions in general... However, it works of course

Comment: @LPs: Absolutely not for something that takes a size in *bytes*, like `snprintf`.

Comment: @FredLarson Only my opinion: "teaching" OP to use that semantic to avoid problem in future...

Comment: @LPs: And run headlong into other problems.

Comment: While it's normally discouraged to have images of text, this is a good example of a question where a screenshot of the console window would help. Please take a screenshot of the "completely broken" console window and edit your question to include it. And while editing your question, please include a proper [mcve], as well as tell us the exact arguments you pass to your program (or perhaps even hardcode the value of `argv[1]`).

Comment: Fomr a C perspective, I think the variable `cmd`cannot be modified by the call to `system`, whatever this function is doing. You can confirm by printing the address of `cmd`, in addition to its content. Is `cmd`on the stack ?

Comment: Might be a subtlety of Windows printf buffering ? try to add a `fflush`in between `printf`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i thought that snprintf length was about the length of data one wants to write. cmd has a fixed length which is the maximum allowed size. According to the info i found online "size" is the maximum number of bytes(characters) that will be written to the buffer so in my case 12 should be the correct number and not sizeof(cmd), am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- One problem: off-by-one

`strlen(argv[1]) + 12` is the expected *length* of the output, yet it is the needed *size* that should be passed to `snprintf()` - a plus one is needed.  Current code is certain to lop off the last character `'\"'` in printing to `cmd`.

```
//                                   12345678901   2
snprintf(cmd, strlen(argv[1]) + 12, "@RD /S /Q \"%s\"", argv[1]);
// better
snprintf(cmd, strlen(argv[1]) + 12 + 1, "@RD /S /Q \"%s\"", argv[1]);
```

This does not well explain the `\0x041f`, perhaps [П](https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=U%2B041F), at the end of OP's output, yet is certainly a problem.

---

- Correct to use size of `cmd` and best to test result before doing a system command with a potentially truncated string.

  ```
  int len = snprintf(cmd, sizeof cmd, "@RD /S /Q \"%s\"", argv[1]);
  if (len < 0 || (unsigned) len >= sizeof cmd) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Forming `cmd` failed\n");
  } else {
    printf("cmd: %s\r\n", cmd);
    system(cmd);
  }
  ```

---

Other issue may exist in the unposted code.